# With homebrew R-gui, unfound object creates segfault "memory not mapped"

Tags: r, segmentation-fault, homebrew

With the homebrew-installed R-gui (`brew install r-gui`), when I call an object which does not exist, I get the following crash:

```
> a
Erreur : objet 'a' introuvable [= not found]

 *** caught segfault ***
address 0x18, cause 'memory not mapped'

Possible actions:
1: abort (with core dump, if enabled)
2: normal R exit
3: exit R without saving workspace
4: exit R saving workspace
```

My configuration: macOS Sierra 10.12.3, MBP (13-inch, Late 2016), with:

```
R version 3.3.2 (2016-10-31) -- "Sincere Pumpkin Patch"
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin16.1.0 (64-bit)

__CF_USER_TEXT_ENCODING          0x1F5:0x0:0x1
LANG                             fr_FR.UTF-8
PATH                             /usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin
R_GUI_APP_REVISION               7203
R_GUI_APP_VERSION                1.68
R_PLATFORM                       x86_64-apple-darwin16.1.0
XPC_FLAGS                        0x0
XPC_SERVICE_NAME                 org.R-project.R.13248
```

I don't have this problem with RStudio, which appears to use the same R. It only indicates that the object does not exist, without crashing.

Any idea of what this `memory not mapped` means, and whether I can fix it?